# history command - 50 entries threshold

Tags: linux

When running *history* in some distro installation(from boot cd) I noticed the entries only go up to 50, overwriting older entries once reaching that threshold.

Is this defined by each distro? or is this 50 entries native in linux?

Is there a way to increase this?

Answer (score 0):

The history length is controlled by the environment variables(s) HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE.

The former refers to the number of history items in memory.
The latter refers to the number of lines in the history-file (~/.bash_history)